# Get net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME using deeplink in android facebook browser

Tags: android, deeplink, appsflyer

when user visit our web site in facebook app(android),

the android download link failed.

The error message is "net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"

our web site is https://ucarer.tw

and the download link is like(with appsflyer tracing)

https://app.appsflyer.com/tw.ucarer.papp?pid=other&c=post_web_lp_ist

IOS, desktop works fine, but not in android

anyone can help? thanks

Comment: I tried from Nexus5x OS7.1.1 - works fine. Please give more info about which Android version, device model ...

Comment: @wilson please also specify which mobile browser was used (chrome, firefox etc.). I also tested this link on S3 Android v4.3 - works well. feel free to contact our support for further assistance at support@appsflyer.com.